# Gatling: Map fields from Json Response to a Map Object

Tags: gatling, jsonpath

My response looks like this

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"919274ee42fe01d40f89f51239009a2b",
         "descriptor":"Long Count_copy_1938",
         "alias":"longCount_Copy_1938",
         "type":"Numeric"
      },
      {
         "id":"435274ee42fe01d40f89f51239009a2b",
         "descriptor":"Long Count2",
         "alias":"longCount_Copy2",
         "type":"Numeric"
      },
      {
         "id":"345274ee42fe01d40f89f51239009a2b",
         "descriptor":"Short Count2",
         "alias":"Short count",
         "type":"Numeric"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to extract "descriptor":"id" to a Map. After mapping, the Map object should look like

```
"Long Count_copy_1938" -> "919274ee42fe01d40f89f51239009a2b"
"Long Count2" -> "435274ee42fe01d40f89f51239009a2b"
"Short Count2" -> "345274ee42fe01d40f89f51239009a2b"
```

Here is how I am achieving it, Let me know if there is a better way. Thanks!

```
exec(http("Get Field ids")
  .get(s"${wqlDataSources}/")
  .check(status.is(200),
  jsonPath("$.data[*].descriptor").findAll.saveAs("descriptors"),
  jsonPath("$.data[*].id").findAll.saveAs("ids")))
.exec(session => {
  val descriptors = session("descriptors").as[Vector[String]]
  val ids = session("ids").as[Vector[String]]
  val fieldIdMap = (descriptors zip ids).toMap
  session.set("fieldIdResultMap", fieldIdMap)
  session.remove("descriptors").remove("ids")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most JSONPath implementations support to extract multiple values in one go using the `[,]` union operator, e.g. `$..['id','descriptor']` to matches your two properties.
<sub>(However, the availability and the result of the union is neither universal nor consistent, if you check the above path [online here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) by switching to Goessner or Jayway you will notice the result are not the same, the Gattling tab on the test site even throws an error; I cannot tell if it would work if the site would use the latest version.)</sub>

I could not find any documentation that confirmed Gatling supports unions but I found [this test](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-jsonpath/src/test/scala/io/gatling/jsonpath/JsonPathSpec.scala) on Gatling's Github repo that has a union: `JsonPath.query("$.menu['file','year']", json) ...` So, unioning should work, in general.

With some trial and error, I found this path that works using Gatling (even with older versions):

```
$.data[*]['id','descriptor']
```

Which returns:

> ```
> [
>    "919274ee42fe01d40f89f51239009a2b",
>    "Long Count_copy_1938",
>    "435274ee42fe01d40f89f51239009a2b",
>    "Long Count2",
>    "345274ee42fe01d40f89f51239009a2b",
>    "Short Count2"
> ]
> ```

So, you should be able to map the key/value pairs in one go using this path!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here is what I did,

{ exec(http("Get Field ids for the data source")
      .get(s"${wqlDataSources}/" + "${datasourceId}/fields?offset=${offset}&limit=100")
      .check(status.is(200),
      jsonPath("$.data[*].descriptor").findAll.saveAs("descriptors"),
      jsonPath("$.data[*].id").findAll.saveAs("ids")))
    .exec(session => {
      val descriptors = session("descriptors").as[Vector[String]]
      val ids = session("ids").as[Vector[String]]
      val currentFieldIdMap = (descriptors zip ids).toMap
})

Comment: @TaraSudarshan Awesome. I am glad this was helpful. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 1 more solution that worked,

```
exec(http("Get Field ids for the data source")
  .get(s"${wqlDataSources}/" + "${datasourceId}/fields)
  .check(status.is(200),
  jsonPath("$.data[*].descriptor").findAll.saveAs("descriptors"),
  jsonPath("$.data[*].id").findAll.saveAs("ids")))
.exec(session => {
  val descriptors = session("descriptors").as[Vector[String]]
  val ids = session("ids").as[Vector[String]]
  val currentFieldIdMap = (descriptors zip ids).toMap
})
```